# C basics, transferring strings or pointers

Tags: c

I have 3 files my_main.c, my_func.c with functions and my_func.h with declarations.

In my_main:

```
#include "my_func.h"

char* database = "mydatabase";
char* dtable = "mytable";

sql_user(mysql_user_name, mysql_password);
sql_table_length(database, dtable, mysql_user_name, mysql_password);
```

In my_func.c

```
#include "my_func.h"

int sql_user(char* mysql_user_name, char* mysql_password)
{
    mysql_user_name = "root";
    mysql_password = "1234";
    return 0;
}
```

In my_func.h

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string.h>

char* mysql_user_name;
char* mysql_password;

int sql_user(char* mysql_user_name, char* mysql_password);
int sql_table_length(char* database, char* dtable, char* mysql_user_name, char* mysql_password);
```

With this code progem compiles with no errors and I would like to get username and password from function in my_func.c file.
But I get value 0x0 while variables declared in main module are reachable and readable.
What to do to get username and password in main in this configuration?

Comment: This shouldn't even link, because you have multiple definitions of `mysql_user_name`...

Comment: Kerrek, this is inside #ifndef but I shorted code here... Anyway, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `sql_user()` to:

```
int sql_user(char** mysql_user_name, char** mysql_password)
{
    *mysql_user_name = "root";
    *mysql_password = "1234";
    return 0;
}
```

And invoke it:

```
sql_user(&mysql_user_name, &mysql_password);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, may I suggest creating a `struct` linked list for your user information like so:

```
typedef struct my_users{
  char *mysql_user_name;
  char *mysql_password;
  USER *next;  // points to the next user in your list if you have more than one, otherwise point to NULL
} USER;
```

And then when calling it (to change the information) you would pass it to the function as `int sql_user(USER *user);` and change it with the call

```
user->mysql_user_name = "root";
user->mysql_password = "1234";
```

And to access it from your main, you can do the same command as above to show the contents.

A benefit of doing it this way, is that all your information is stored together. For instance, if you have multiple users, the passwords and names would not get mixed up by a small error in logic. Also, using linked lists, you are able to count how many `nodes` you have in your list, aka how many entries, by simply traversing the list.

I hope you find this useful! Cheers

[This should show you more about linked lists if you're interested.](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/)

Comment: The OPs question didn't have anything to do with linked lists... it's simple pointer-to-pointer confusion. This answer isn't enlightening the OP as to why their current solution doesn't work... it's providing an alternative "solution" to a problem the answerer doesn't even know if the OP is facing or not (complexity and maintainability).

Comment: Having seen a good answer already posted solving their initial problem, I posted an alternate solution in case the OP was interested in experimenting and trying another method. Personally, I enjoy learning experiences like that, so was introducing a different perspective to solving their objective.

Comment: iKiair thank you, very interesting and usable alternative. I will spend some time for this for sure!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicate definitions of a variable, you should define your variables in a source file and use the `extern` keyword in a header so that other translation units know about the variable.

**EDIT:** You don't have the above problem, since `mysql_user_name` and `mysql_password` are simply declared in the header file, I just merely wanted to point it out since it's the usual practice, and if you did define the variables you'd have a linker error.

Also, `sql_user()` isn't doing what you're wanting it to do:

```
int sql_user(char* mysql_user_name, char* mysql_password)
{
    mysql_user_name = "root";
    mysql_password = "1234";
    return 0;
}
```

That's causing the local variables `mysql_user_name` and `mysql_password` to point to `"root"` and `"1234"`. If you want to modify the pointers passed to `sql_user`, use a `char**`, ie:

```
int sql_user(char** mysql_user_name, char** mysql_password)
{
    *mysql_user_name = "root";
    *mysql_password = "1234";
    return 0;
}
```

Then pass the address of `mysql_user_name` and `mysql_password` when calling the function from `my_main` (`&mysql_user_name` and `&mysql_password`).

Note also that these string literals are read-only, and every two pointers passed to `sql_user` will be pointing to the same `"root"` and `"1234"` strings.

Comment: Where does he have duplicate definitions of the same variables? If not for that bit i'd +1 because it's a better explanation of why he needs to use pointers to pointers.

Comment: @Steve: Having `char* mysql_user_name;` and `char* mysql_password;` *can* cause a duplicate symbol error when linking if it's included in multiple sources. I added that part because I thought it was worth noting. EDIT: Woops I see now, they're just declared and not defined in that header. I still think it's worth noting for the future. Anyway I didn't say he had that problem, just that if he did have multiple definitions it'd cause problems.

Comment: If you're going to critique every possible misstep he *could* be making - then you'd probably need to add something about header guards as well.

Comment: @Steve: Yeah true, but I thought it'd be partly relevant since he was focussing on those variables.

Comment: Sorry, I shortened code to concentrate my actual problem. I uses #ifndef MY_FUNC_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_FUNC_H_INCLUDED ...  #endif